# Why evm assembly push4 sometimes doesn't push the value in parameter?

Tags: remix, evm, assembly

I'm analyzing the fail of [this tx on goerli](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xacd5f8c9220ab3051e6c55455097b0075fbb30f427df8b21c8b0437a8aeb10b7)

My question is not really about the tx, but about a strange behaviour when I debug it on remix.

I'm calling a proxy who called the implementation with delegatecall. the opcodes I'm following now are from the implementation contract, and remix shows me a stack... push4 always behaviored as expected since the the beginning of the tx, but at this point, a different value appears on the stack.

Why b61d27f6 appears on the stack instead of a02fcc0a ?

before push4 :

[image: before]

after push4 :

[image: after]

Comment: That's interesting, could you share some code to reproduce that behavior ? I'm leaning towards an issue in the way remix displays the stack / instructions, but there's no way to be sure without seeing some code.

Comment: You should reproduce with following theses steps. Further push4 fails too, it seems appears in implementation code only.
- Create an instance on the Puzzle Wallet level of ethernaut wargame
- copy/paste code in remix and load contract from addresses with injected provider on goerli
- on the puzzle proxy contract, create a tx with the following calldata :
b7b0422d00000000000000000000000019d67dbe3018e2565a7b17fe7f673770bc95a3ff
(calling init(uint256) of the implementation with the address used to create the instance. Yeah it fails but it's another problem... One at a time...)

Comment: I have the expected stack by debugging a call on `init` with the value `0x00000000000000000000000019d67dbe3018e2565a7b17fe7f673770bc95a3ff` on the deployed `puzzleWallet`.

Comment: Have you used remix also ? or another tool ?

Comment: Yes I did it with remix, but if the sources do not match perfectly the debugging feature is almost useless, did you verify your contract and / or ensured that your remix bytecode matched perfectly the deployed one ?

Comment: This could be a bug in Remix. I think it may be better to open an issue or discussion on remix github for this question